# t-sql procedure has no errors but need to be enhanced

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written a procedure in T-SQL which returns errorcount based on state code,fiscal year etc..., but it has 3 pieces involved:
1. it returns inner join of 2 tables to pull selective columns
2. a case statement with multiple value possibility for coloffset
3. function to return errorcount.

When I run the code it gives output with 3 separate tables, but, I intend to get errorcount as the only output. How can I accomplish this. The oracle equivalent used cursor. Do I need to use it here?

Here's the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [hsip].[ErrorCount] (
    @cRegion CHAR(2) ='00',
    @cState_Code CHAR(2) = '00',
    @nFY NUMERIC(4,0) = 0,
    @nREPORT_ID NUMERIC(2,0) = 0,
    @nSECTION_ID NUMERIC(2,0) = 0,
    @nSUBSECTION_ID NUMERIC(2,0) = 0,
    @nDISPLAY_NUMBER NUMERIC(38,0) = 0,
    @nQUESTION_NUMBER NUMERIC(38,0) = 0,
    @nQUESTION_PART_NUMBER NUMERIC(38,0) = 0,
    @suser_id varchar(25) =NULL,
   @nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID numeric(38,0))

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

--declare nfy_st_question_dtl_table_id as integer

--declare ncolumn_index cursor for
declare @coloffset as integer
--@temptbl as numeric(38,0)


select qi.REGION, qi.STATE_CODE, qi.FY, qi.REPORT_ID, qi.SECTION_ID, qi.SUBSECTION_ID, qi.DISPLAY_NUMBER, qi.QUESTION_NUMBER, qd.QUESTION_PART_NUMBER 
from FY_ST_QUESTION_DETAIL qd inner join FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO qi
on qd.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID =  qi.FY_ST_QUESTION_INFO_TABLE_ID
where qi.region = @cRegion
         and qi.state_code = @cState_Code
         and qi.fy = @nFY
         and qi.report_id = @nREPORT_ID
         and qi.section_id = @nSECTION_ID
         and qi.subsection_id = @nSUBSECTION_ID
         and qi.display_number = @nDISPLAY_NUMBER
         and qi.QUESTION_NUMBER = @nQUESTION_NUMBER
         and ( QI.REPORTER_ID = @sUSER_ID or
               QI.DELEGATE_ID = @suser_id or
               QI.SUB_DELEGATE_ID = @suser_id )
         and QD.QUESTION_PART_NUMBER = @nQUESTION_PART_NUMBER ;


        set @coloffset=
            case
           when (@nREPORT_ID = 1 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 21) then  17
            when (@nREPORT_ID = 1 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 32) then  16
            when (@nREPORT_ID = 3 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 11) then  15
            when (@nREPORT_ID = 3 and @nQUESTION_NUMBER = 12) then  27
        end;

     select [hsip].[getErrorCount](@nFY_ST_QUESTION_DTL_TABLE_ID, 0, @coloffset)as ErrCount;    

END
```

thanks,

Comment: I don't see how this code can generate an output with 3 tables.  It only has 2 selects.

Comment: the third table is coming from the function geterrorcount. I can post the code

Comment: In that case, where is the second table coming from?

Comment: I still see only 2 select statements, the first one 'select qi.REGION' and the second using the function. What the is the first select statement used for in this SProc?

Answer (score 0):

Comment out or delete the SELECT statements that generate the tables that you don't want in your output.

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. you are right, it returns 2 tables and  need the output to be error count. I was confused by the return type value. Again my bad..

Comment: I doubt that will work -- is the output of the function deterministic without the select statements -- they are -- for example the 2nd one changes a variable used in the function call.  of course we can't be sure without seeing the source for that function.

Comment: The one that changes a variable wouldn't return a table, and I don't see how the one that returns a table can possibly affect the output of the function.